# Difference between random vector and joint distribution

Tags: random-variable, multivariate-distribution

My definition of a random vector is a vector $(x_{1},...,x_{n})$ that maps from a sample space to ${R}^{n}$. An example of this (in my understanding) would be a random process such as drawing one card from a deck. Let us say all potential suits of the card are the sample space {hearts, clubs, diamonds, spades}. An example of a random vector is a vector $(X_{1}, X_{2})$, where $X_{1}, X_{2}$ each map the same sample space to real numbers.

In slide 6 at this [link](https://engineering.purdue.edu/ChanGroup/ECE302/files/Slide_5_01.pdf) it describes a joint RV that considers the outcome of a coin flip and a dice roll. In this case, the two sample spaces {H,T} and {1,2,3,4,5,6} are disjoint. Would this example not be considered a random vector, then?

My confusion is the difference between these two constructions.

Comment: It is a very nice question which I also could not find any answers for. One thing that comes to my mind is that if $x_1$ and $x_2$ belong to $\mathbb{R}^2$ and $x_1 = (a,b)$ and $x_2 = (b,a)$ then $p(\vec{x_1})$ is not necessarily equal to $p(\vec{x_2})$ since they are two different vectors. However if we talk about the joint probability of $a$ and $b$, then $p(a,b) = p(b,a)$. I am not sure if this is a correct statement since I am a beginner in probability theory and just began reading up on measure theory. So I would be glad if someone could elaborate on this.

Comment: I think there was a little bit of notation abuse in my previous comment. What I meant was that if we talk about the joint probability of $y_1 = a$ and $y_2 =b$, then $p(y_1=a, y_2=b) = p(y_2=b, y_1=a)$ where $y_1$ and $y_2$ belong to $\mathbb{R}$.